# Bluetooth disconnects when starting to play music

Tags: bluetooth, connection-issues, headphones, bluetooth-audio, headset

I have a Jabra Move headset that has been working wonderfully for months. However, today it started having connection problems to my Motorola Moto Z: it connects and remains connected indefinitely, as long as I don't start playing any sound.

If I have sound from Google Music or Facebook, the headset plays 3 seconds, disconnects, and reconnects. I have no idea how to solve this.

Here's what I tried:

1. Restarting the mobile phone
2. Restarting the headset
3. Reset the headset
4. Unpairing and pairing back

I am running Android 7.1.1.
I have no idea how to fix this, please help.

Comment: From the bluetooth settings try up-pairing the headset. And then pairing it again you can test if this works.

Comment: @rajat do you mean unpairing? I have tried it as well :(

Answer (score 0):

Please do share which version of Android is installed.

Assumption made, there was a recent update to Moto Z  to Android 7.1. There is a high possibility that the bluetooth headset + Moto Z + Wifi versions are now at conflict. From experience with most bluetooth devices, Moto Z will have to rollout a fix or you can get another headset.

Or you can try this

1. Disable the wifi + hotspot.
2. Unpair the devices.
3. Restart both Moto Z handset and the headphone.
4. Pair both devices.

Looks like a long list, but takes less than 2 minutes to do. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I am running Android 7.1.1. I will try your suggestion, but it is weird since other bluetooth headsets work properly